# What will be the maximum limit for Int(8) Unsigned in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, int, sqldatatypes

What is the maximum value that Int(8) can hold? Is there a difference between Int(8) and Int(11)?

Comment: This should help you :http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/369/int5-vs-smallint5

Comment: See also here: https://alexander.kirk.at/2007/08/24/what-does-size-in-intsize-of-mysql-mean/

Comment: `int` means that 4 bytes are allocated for the value. The number in brackets only defines how many digits will be displayed. So, if you had `int(1)`, it can hold 4.2 billion values but it will always display 1 digit.

Comment: The `(8)` has meaning only if you have `ZEROFILL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signed ranges between -2147483648 and 2147483647
Unsigned ranges between 0 and 4294967295

In MySQL, int numbers between brackets define the display width. They will, however, not cut off the number if the int is larger than the display width. You will mostly see the effect of int numbers when using zerofill.

More info: https://alexander.kirk.at/2007/08/24/what-does-size-in-intsize-of-mysql-mean/